# Mesh files folder to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, office365

So, I have a doubt. I have some pdf files (around 2000) that I want to upload as attachments in a sharepoint list. But I don't want to upload all the files in one item. In the list, I have the same 2000 items (the files are named with the same ID as the items). Whats the correct way to upload them? Theres a way to mesh the files with items (one for each)? Or should I use another feature that I dont know? Such as libraries?

[pdf list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FNqO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi João Guilherme Bezerra Alves,

You can take advantage of powershell, please take a reference of below steps:

1. prepare list items

[image]

2. prepare files

[image]

3. run below script:

```html
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/abc"
$ListName = "yourlistname"

$Username='abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
$Password = '***'

#region Credentials
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials
 
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

$Folderpath ="D:\mypdffolder"

ForEach ($File in  (Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -File))
{
    # try to find the corresponding item (has the same id)
    $caml= @"
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                <Value Type='Text'>$($File.Name)</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
"@

    $Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $caml   
    if($Items -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Do not find such an item that has the same id: $($File.Name)"
        Continue
    }

    if($Items -is [system.array]){
        $Item = $Items[0]
    }else{
        $Item = $Items
    }        
        
    $AttachmentInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCreationInformation 
    $AttachmentInfo.FileName =  $File.Name
    $AttachmentInfo.ContentStream = $File.OpenRead()
    $AttchedFile = $Item.AttachmentFiles.Add($AttachmentInfo) 

    Invoke-PnPQuery  
    $AttachmentInfo.ContentStream.Close()    
}
```

Reference doc:

- [Get-PnPListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [SharePoint Online: Add Attachment to List Item using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-add-attachment-to-list-item-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 0):

A friend at reddit also posted a solution using flow. Both where very good indeed! Thanks man!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cscoo.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/088jO.png

Credit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/ha2j9v/mesh_files_folder_to_sharepoint_list/